# Take data from one field and insert into new row

Tags: linux, awk

I have a tsv like below:

```
1   2   3   4,5,6   a
1   2   3       b
2   7   9   1,2 c   
0   7   9   1,6,7,7 d
```

I need to extract the 4th column take the values separated by the commas and place them into their own row, giving them their own row if there is more than 1 value in the column. e.g:

```
1   2   3   4   a
            5
            6
            7       
1   2   3       b
2   7   9   1   c   
            2           
0   7   9   1   d
            6
            7
            7
```

I tried:

```
awk -F'\t' '{split($4,a,",");for(i in a)if(!seen[a[i]]++)print a[i]}' /report/temp2.tsv > /report/temp3.tsv
```

I'm missing the rest though...

Comment: there's no `7` value in the 1st row, why does it appear in the result?

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NF == 4{ $4 = OFS $4 }
     NF == 5 && $4 ~ /,/{
         len = split($4, a, ",");
         sub(/,.+/, "", $4); print $0;
         for(i = 2; i <= len; i++) print OFS OFS OFS a[i];
         next
    }1' OFS='\t' file
```

The output:

```
1   2   3   4   a
            5
            6
1   2   3       b
2   7   9   1   c
            2
0   7   9   1   d
            6
            7
            7
```